# I am creating a class with two methods that return two lists but only the first list is getting populated whereas the second list remains empty

Tags: apex, class, method

```
public with sharing class ProductController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Category__c> getCategories() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Category__c with Security_enforced];  
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Product__c> getProductsByCategory(String categoryName) {
        List<Product__c> products;

        if (categoryName == null) {
            System.debug('CategoryName is null. Fetching all products');
            products = [SELECT Id, Name, MRP__c, Product_s_Brand__r.Name FROM Product__c with Security_enforced];
        } else {
            System.debug('Fetching products for Category: ' + categoryName);
            products = [SELECT Id, Name, MRP__c, Product_s_Brand__r.Name FROM Product__c
                        WHERE Product_s_Brand__r.Category__r.Name = :categoryName with Security_enforced];
        }
        System.debug('Number of products retrieved: ' + products.size());
        return products;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if Product_s_Brand__r.Category__r.Name is accessible in the class.In most cases i have seen the Name of parent of parent is not directly accessible in apex .

You can have a for loop to access the value.

Comment: Hey thanks ,  I have edited my code using the for loop but I still cannot find the output, if possible can you please help me how to write this class with for loop.